# How to pass data from parent to child component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

When I try to pass data from parent to child component. I'm getting undefined message in the console. Data is in the form of array.

**parent.component.html**

```
<div class="section welcome-section fp-section fp-table" *ngFor="let section of sections">
    <div class="fp-tableCell">
      <app-question-card [data]="section"></app-question-card>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input() data;
  question = [];
  constructor() {
    this.question = this.data;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.question); //returns undefined
  }
```

Comment: Move assignment to `ngOnInit`. `@Input` is not available until `ngOnChanges`

Comment: Shouldn't the input properties already be hydrated in ngOnInit?

Comment: `constructor => ngOnChanges => ngOnInit => ngAfterContentInit ...`

Comment: @Jota.Toledo `ngOnChanges` is fired before `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can't do the assignment in the constructor as the value has not yet been populated, it should be done in `ngOnInit` just like your check of the value.

```
@Input() data;
question = [];

constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.question = this.data;
  console.log(this.question);
}
```

Comment: Hello @Igor, my requirement is almost same as i need to get Id from my parent component to child component on when i click on the button. 
But i am getting this error `Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'editId' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.` 
Can you pls help ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-duduth

Comment: Please ask a new question on [so] @aananddham, asking a question in the comments of an existing question or answer is the wrong place in this forum.

Comment: how can i get updated data in `@Input`? i have an array in my parent component and after an API request data get updated in parent component how can i update my Child component with updated data.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib - please create a new question with all of the relevant information. Try to create an [mcve] in your question.

Comment: i managed  to solve it via `onChanges`.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using `Input()`decorator. See below code -

> parent.component.ts -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-child [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-child>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent{
  parentMessage = "message from parent"
  constructor() { }
}
```

> child.component.ts -

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
      Say {{ childMessage}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() childMessage: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

More [Information](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

Answer (score 3):

According to angular Lifecycle use the ngOnInit for initializing input values

```
@Input() data;


constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {
  let question = this.data;
  console.log(this.question);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I didnt go through the above answers. Will keep these in mind  :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Input() we can pass data

> Child.html

```
<app-chart [userDetails]='<< JSON OBJ | ANY VALUE WHICH YOU WANT TO PASS >>'></app-chart>
```

> chart.component.ts

```
@Input() userDetails: any = [];

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.userDetails); // as per angular Lifecycle use the ngOnInit for initializing input values
}
```