# Angular *ngFor with nested component

Tags: angular, ngfor

so i got a a parent-component in which i have another child-component. I want to use the data i got form the ngFor in the parent component inside the child-component.

example:

parent component

```html
<div *ngFor= "let item of items"> 
 item name in parent component: {{item.name}}
<child-component></child-component>
</div>
```

child component

```html
<div> item name in child component {{item.name}}</div>
```

i hope u get want i want!

ty

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189314/how-to-pass-data-from-parent-to-child-component-in-angular-4/45189427

Comment: Use [`@Input`](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-child-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data to child components from the parent component by creating an [`@Input()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) variable on the child component, then passing the data to that variable in the template.

This is the parent component. Its template has the child component. As seen, it has an attribute called `item`, which matches the property name on the child component.

**Note:** I renamed the let variable to make it easier to understand.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `<div *ngFor= "let parentItem of items"> 
    item name in parent component: {{parentItem.name}}
    <child-component [item]="parentItem"></child-component>
  </div>`
})
export class ParentComponent {
  items = [{name: 'Hello World'}]
}
```

Here we have our child component. It has a property `item` attached to an `@Input()`. The input tells the child component that the value may come from an attribute of a component that uses this component in its template.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `<div> item name in child component {{item.name}}</div>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input()
  item = { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @pzaenger mentioned in the comments you should use `@Input()` if you want to pass parameters to your child component.

```html
<!-- On the parent.component.html -->
<child-component *ngFor="let i of items" [item]="i"></child-component>
```

```js
// On the child component TS file
@Component({...})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() public item: YourType;
}
```

```html
<!-- On the template file -->
<h1>Some text and {{item.property}}</h1>
```

If you'd like to pass HTML content to your child component use this pattern:

```html
<!-- On the parent.component.html -->

<child-component *ngFor="let i of items">
    item name in child component {{item.name}}
</child-component>
```

```html
<!-- on the child.component.html -->
<div class="your-classes-here">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```