# Pass data from parent component to child component in angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-components, ngonchanges

I have 2 components. I want to pass data from parent component to child component & generate the child html based on a drop down option selection in parent component.

This is my parent component html

```
<select
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="optionType"
  (change)="onItemSelect($event)"
>
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option *ngFor="let value of values" [ngValue]="value.id">
    {{ value.itemName }}
  </option>
</select>
<app-child-component *ngIf="info.length>0" [info]="info"></app-child-component>
```

This is my parent component class

Based on this `onItemSelect(event: any)` method i want to load values for `this.info`.

```
  onItemSelect(event: any) {
    if (this.value === 'value1') {
      this.service.getDetails().subscribe(
        (res) => {
          this.info = res;
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

This is my child component file

```
@Input() info: Info[];
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(this.info);
    this.createForm();
  }
```

This is the form

```
  createForm() {
    const group = {};
    this.info.forEach((field) => {
      group[field.label] = new FormControl('');
    });
    this.fieldForm = new FormGroup(group);
  }
```

After selecting the value in this method `onItemSelect($event)`. I can see values in child component `console.log(this.info)`  But child component html does n't load. What is the reason for that & how to load child component html according to drop down value selection.

Comment: What html you want to generate in child componenet upon `this.info` changes

Comment: I want to generate a form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data from parent to child component in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189314/how-to-pass-data-from-parent-to-child-component-in-angular-4)

Comment: @Mands make small demo here, so other can understand it more.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda when I click on a create button parent component will load. after that based on `onItemSelect($event)` method option selection response will load to the `this.info`. variable. and rest of the form will load according to the values in `this.info`

Comment: At the 1 st time when i click on create button `this.info` length is 0. Only after the option selection `this.info`  will have the values

Comment: What data is inside `info`? How you tried to create form in child component